# Unity output error when creating the output

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

## **Hello to all.**

I made a small 2D game in my Unity, and after the completion of the construction, **I want to output from it, but I am facing an error and I have tried many ways to solve it, but they have not worked**, until I reached here, I want to ask you friends. Dear, I need help.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ZoM.png)

I have bought and downloaded Unity normally and it is the original version, but I don't know what is the problem of this error!

[Getting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnqIf.png)

[And this damn error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYiOe.png)

Unity version: 2020.3.4
Windows version: 10

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me!

My friends said that it might be the problem with the internet, but it wasn't my problem, and I even uninstalled and reinstalled Unity, but it didn't work.

Console errors :

[Hmmm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1uHF.png)

more...

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease FAILED
40 actionable tasks: 40 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

----------------


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download lint-checks-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.0.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.0.1/lint-checks-27.0.1.jar'.
         > Read timed out
   > Could not download uast-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.0.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/27.0.1/uast-27.0.1.jar'.
         > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 53s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)


------------------------

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 378 seconds (378278 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

-----------------------

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002cc] in <2cd7f07c7b884ea9bf02386eb91a464c>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <2cd7f07c7b884ea9bf02386eb91a464c>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

----------------
```

pls help :/

Comment: and without wanting to sound too sarcastic but well it well, so what does the console say? like it says?

Comment: You should upload console error

Comment: I just posted the console errors...